# Read only Dictionary - multiple threads calling .ContainsKey method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, dictionary

I have a static **readonly** dictionary. **No** modifications will be made to this dictionary.

I have multiple threads reading from this dictionary using the  .ContainsKey(Key). e.g.

```
class MyData
{ 
    private static private IDictionary<int, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    MyData()
    {
        // Load Dictionary here
    }

    public string GetValue(int key)
    {
        if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        { 
            return _dictionary[key];   
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any threading problems with doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If nobody is mutating it: this is fine. If there were *occasional* edits, then perhaps look at ReaderWriterLockSlim, or (my preference) edit a snapshot/copy and swap the reference.

Comment: But you would still need the ReaderWriterLockSlim whilst swapping the reference, right?

Comment: @Mark: Writing a reference is guaranteed to be atomic, but I guess you'd probably want to mark the field `volatile` to ensure that any other threads see the change.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that if you swap out the reference whilst it's in the middle of running the ContainsKey method then it might cause problems?

Comment: @Mark: You should aim to use `TryGetValue` rather than `dict.ContainsKey` followed by `dict[key]`. If you do that then the old ref will be read *once* atomically and you'll get your value from the old copy of the dictionary.

Comment: Sounds great. But just leaves me confused about the purpose of locks given you can just use the edit / swap reference pattern to make updates

Comment: @Mark - with TryGetValue you only dereference once, so the behaviour is well-defined (it works); if you do a separate ContainsKey then fetch, you need to *either* copy the reference into a local variable, else risk the second dereference being a different dictionary with different data.

Answer (score 5):

It is safe if you are only going to read.

Answer (score 2):

if all of the 'adding' is complete before you read from multiple threads then it is fine. Just because its readonly doesnt mean its thread safe - which it isnt.

Maybe you should user `ReaderWriterLock` to synchronise access

Answer (score 2):

If you were to be writing data at the same time (and you were using .NET 4.0) then you could use the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)