# Is it safe to enumerate over a shared array in C# for read-only access?

Tags: c#, arrays, thread-safety, enumeration

I have an array of valid string values like this:

```
string[] validValues = new string[] {"none","all","some"};
```

I have a method that validates a user's selection in a drop down box like this:

```
bool valid = validValues.Contains( selection );
```

I don't want to re-create the `validValues` array every time this method is called, so I'd like to assign it to a `static readonly` property.  The array itself is immutable. Is this scenario thread-safe?  This is part of an MVC controller method, so it's quite possible that multiple threads will be accessing the array via the `Enumerable<string>.Contains` method at the same time.

If the enumeration is not thread safe, then would it be thread safe to use a method like `Array.IndexOf` instead?  Decompiling shows that the method either calls the native method TrySZIndexOf, or it iterates over the array by index. From what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460660/88409), that may be safe?  I'd just rather use Contains because it conveys what's trying to be accomplished more clearly than `IndexOf() == -1`.

Comment: Yes, iterating over it is completely thread safe as long as the array never changes. You may want to use an immutable `HashSet` instead though, that way you won't need the iteration.

Comment: Yes, since it is read only

Comment: As @JoachimIsaksson said, a hash set will be faster for actually doing your look-ups, and you can delcare `validValues` as an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` to signal the immutable nature of the collection.

Comment: AS IT IS  WRITTEN in your first two code quotes, certainly not.  IF indeed you add readonly as you mention - then yes.  (As everyone has mentioned, use a readonly HashSet here)

Comment: Your specific scenario -- immutable array, initialized in a readonly static field -- sounds quite threadsafe. However, be cautious in extrapolating from this fact; people occasionally get into a bad way when they incorrectly think that everything in a static initializer becomes threadsafe by magic. If you want to know what static initializers actually do, a good place to start your researches is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398509/how-does-a-static-constructor-work/9399027#9399027

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this access is thread safe (assuming array is never modified).

You can also use standard [`Dictionary`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287075/read-only-dictionary-multiple-threads-calling-containskey-method) or [`HashSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131255/is-a-read-only-hashset-inherently-threadsafe) if it works better as both are also safe for read-only multithreaded access.

If you concerned that one can change array by mistake - consider using new Immutable types like [ImmutableList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx).

---

Generic discussion that covers the resononing - [Why are immutable objects thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595114/why-are-immutable-objects-thread-safe). Additionally there is series of articles by Eric Lippert on [immutable data structures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/immutability/page/3/), and [Read-only and theradsafe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different/) touches on topic of such access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As you are declaring it as read only, it is thread safe.

You may use ReadOnlyCollection class in C# rather declaring an array as read only.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The `readonly` field modifier and the `ReadOnlyCollection` type do not mean the same thing, and it's important not to confuse them. The `readonly` field modifier guarantees that the value of the *field* does not change. For a collection (or any other reference type), this means that you cannot assign an entirely new collection to the member - but you can freely modify the collection the member points to. `ReadOnlyCollection`s guarantee that elements of the collection do not change, i.e. `collection[0]` cannot become a different object.